# Reset component value in a form

Tags: angularjs

I have a component which gets initialized with a value got from an ajax request in its controller $postLink event. This component is inside a form.

Then the user may change the default value and then submit. When the form is submitted, the component value becomes blank. I need to find a way to reinitialize back to the value got from the ajax request, but of course the $postLink event cannot fire again since the component has already been created.

Component js:

```
app.component('formFieldPortafoglioSelector', {
    templateUrl: 'ngComponents/form-field-portafoglio-selector.html',
    bindings: {
        label: '@',
        model: '='
    },
    controller: ['$scope', 'ApiService', function($scope, ApiService) {
        var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.$postLink = function() {
            ApiService.domini.then(function(response) {
                $scope.portafogli = response.domini.portafogli;
                ctrl.model = $scope.portafogli[0].id_ptf;
            });
        };
    }]
});
```

Component Template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm">{{ $ctrl.label }}</label>
    <select class="form-control custom-select"
            ng-options="ptf.id_ptf as ptf.des_ptf for ptf in portafogli"
            ng-model="$ctrl.model"
            >
    </select>
</div>
```

Component Usage:

```
<div ng-controller="resourceController as rc">
    <form ng-submit="rc.operazione.$save()">
        <form-field-portafoglio-selector model="rc.operazione.id_ptf_sorgente" label="Portafoglio Sorgente">
        </form-field-portafoglio-selector>
    </form>
</div>
```

The Resource Controller is defined as follows:

```
app.controller('resourceController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {
    this.operazione = new $resource('operazioni', null, {})();
}]);
```

Comment: I think you need to show more code of what makes the form values blank. Probably something in ng-submit... I'm willing to bet model values are cleared out there... Have you considered moving the fetching of the data outside the component and passing it in as an attribute?

Comment: Is there a reason for using $postLink? I don't see any reason for it from your code

Comment: I added more code for clarification. Patrick you're right it's the $save in the submit which resets to blank the component value. pegla no need to use $postLink indeed, I didn't know where to put some non trivial initialization code (i.e. the ajax request)

Comment: another question not so relevant...is there a reason to keep only portafogli on $scope, you can just keep it on controller as rest of the stuff you have?

Comment: no reason, the code is still messy because I'm experimenting different approaches to get used to angularjs...

Comment: You will probably want to pass the data to the component and initialize that data in your controller where you are retrieving the resource. That way when you save, you can just persist whatever values you have on your model so they stay in the form.

Comment: I didn't think about it, quite simple and works well, thanks. Now the component doesn't even need a controller (and neither the $postLink function). It just bind the selected value and the select domain. From the outer controller I can set any default value and any domain.